# Java regex: Matching Substring with newline followed by whitespace

Tags: java, regex, newline, whitespace

I am currently trying to extract Substrings from Strings by matching them with a regular expression. The input-strings are all in the form `foo.bar("""foobar""")`, where foobar is the substring I would like to extract.
This is the regular expression I wrote for this task:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            ".+\\(\"{3}(.+)\"{3}\\)" , Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

It matches well against simple Strings, but fails whenever a newline followed by a whitespace occurs in the String to be matched, i.e. `foo.bar("""foo\n bar""")`

How do I have to change my pattern so that it matches those strings as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `Pattern.DOTALL` instead of `Pattern.MULTILINE`. `Pattern.MULTILINE` is about behaviour of `^` and `$` and has nothing to do with matching newlines with `.`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
     ".+\\(\"{3}(.+)\"{3}\\)" , Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it :-) I forgot to replace MULTILINE by DOTALL when I changed my pattern midway to use `(.+)` instead of `([^"{3}]+)`... Silly mistake .)

Comment: JeanMarie, you should click the check mark on the left of his answer so he gets credit for answering.